# Phonegap intercept jQueryMobile Ajax calls

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I've the requirement to intercept an jquery mobile Ajax request in phonegap - natively in iOS and Android. If the user requests specific URLs i have to fetch data from a local datastore - e.g. File or Database and pass the Data back to jquery.

Can anybody tell me how i can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: show us your code first

Comment: If you want to access the content of a local file you can use the File API (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html). But then you have to know exactly where the file is stored and you need the permission to access it. I don't  think that this is a kind of good approach. What do you really want to do with your application?

Comment: the application should provide a native cache that is filled by http webservice calls in regular intervals. in jquery in the $ajax i need to fetch the data either from the cache or from the url provided in the ajax function. i have to implement offline enabled jquery mobile app based on phonegap...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redefine the $.ajax function like this:

```
$.originalAjaxFunction=$.ajax;
$.ajax=function(params){
    if(testCache){ //test params.url to check if it's already in the cache
        //get from local cache
    }
    else
        $.originalAjaxFunction(params);
}
```

note that if you need to use promises, you will have to add extra lines in the function.